# Error creating bean with name cloudFoundryDatabaseConfig

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cloud, pcf

I have updated spring boot version from 2.6.6 to 2.7.11 and spring cloud version 2012.0.4 after updating I m facing issue like creating bean with name cloudFoundryDatabaseConfig

I want to update spring boot version and spring cloud

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.